# Magento orders stuck in payment_review: how does one release? and is stock reserved?

Tags: stock, status, order-state

we are seeing several orders with status/state both `payment_review`. And we are running a script that cleans up and releases the stock of order like 'payment_approval', `payment_review` and 'pending_payment'. There is a check on canCancel() in the routing and this is where the process of `payment_review` differs: it returns false and as such we cannot cancel these orders ... what to do?

So my questions is:

- Order with state/status `payment_review` have already blocked/reserved stock (read: deducted the qty for the order from total stock). Am I right?
- And these orders should also be released after X days for the stock to become available again.

Help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to remove the check `$order->canCancel()`

because it can be cancelled (and cleared after X days)